# QJSonArray to QString conversion

Tags: c++, qt5, qstring

I have this 2 variables, and I want to convert data to dataToString.

```
QJSonArray data;

Qstring dataToString;
```

In data there is a huge json like:

```
{
    "properties": [
        {
            "version":"1",
            "finish":"0",
            "num":3,
            "running":false,
            "time":"00:20:00",
            "player1":"John",
            "player2":"",
            "player3": "Peter",
            "player4":"",
            "team1":"",
            "team2":"",
            "tournament":"",
            "lap":""
        }
    ],
    "game": [
        {
            "serve":true,
            "score":"32",
            "data":"0"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I do it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To quote [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonarray.html):

> You can convert the array to and from text based JSON through
>   QJsonDocument.

In other words, all you need to do is this:

```
QJsonArray data;
QJsonDocument doc;
doc.setArray(data);

QString dataToString(doc.toJson());
```

That's all there is to it!

Comment: `QJSonArray  ⇒ QJsonArray  QJSonDocument  ⇒  QJsonDocument `

Comment: And you can use `doc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact)` instead of `doc.toJson()` to get a compact string whitout format and Line break :)